# Error message appearing twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I am learning JSF and need some help. I am trying to do a declarative validation in a page, the rendered required message however appears twice in the HTML markup.

In my managed bean i have a `students` field pointing to a student entity which has the following fields `firstName`, `otherNames`, `surName`.

this is how the **Managed Bean** looks like:

```
@ViewScoped
public Class FormController implements Serializeble{
 private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

  @PostConstruct
  public void init(){
   students.add(new Student());
   students.add(new Student());
    }

  //getters and setters
}
```

then in my **JSF Page**, I have a `ui:repeat` that points to `students` in my bean with declarative validation on the input fields;

```
    <h:form>
      <table>
       <ui:repeat value="#{formController.students}" var="student">
        <tr>
         <td><p:outputLabel value="first name:"/></td>
         <td><p:inputText value="#{student.firstname}" 
                          required="true" 
                          requiredMessage="field cannot be blank"/></td>
         <td><p:messages/></td>
        </tr>

        <!--other input fields omitted to make code cleaner-->

       </ui:repeat>
      </table>
      <p:commandButton value="submit" 
                       action="#{formController.saveStudents()}"/>
    </h:form>
```

**The Problem**, 
I am facing hereof is that, the required message are generated twice for each input field in the HTML markup like this:

```
<span class="bf-message">
    <span class="bficon bficon-error-circle-o bf-message-icon" aria-hidden="true</span>
    <span class="bf-message-detail">this feild cant be left blank</span></span><br /><span class="bf-message">
    <span class="bficon bficon-error-circle-o bf-message-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="bf-message-detail">this feild cant be left blank</span></span>


 //repeated likewise for all other input field required message,omitted to save space
```

This is my development Enviroment

- GlassFish 4.1.1
- JSF 2.2
- Primefaaces 6.0
- NetBeans IDE.

To add a little more details,the backing bean method that the commandButtion action points to has no FacesMessages, neither do the Field in the Entity Class have validation annotations.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you nested `<p:messages />` inside a `<ui:repeat>`. Since the `ui:repeat` iterates over all students you add to the list during render response phase, you end up with one message component for each student you add. A `p:messages` component by default displays all messages added to the FacesContext (e.g. all validation messages).

Move the `<p:messages />` out of the `<ui:repeat>` and the messages will only be displayed once.

Another solution, if you want the message to be displayed right at the `inputText`, would be to give the `inputText` component an `id` attribute and use this `id` attribute in your `<p:messages />` as a `for` attribute. Of course, this `id` has to be unique. The `for` attribute makes the `messages` component only display messages that were added for this particular component. This, however does not work with `<ui:repeat>`, as `ui:repeat` only renders the components multiple times but does not actually create multiple components in the component tree. So you'd have to use `<c:forEach>` for this. Make sure to read [this introduction to JSTL tags in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) first though.

```
<p:inputText id="#{student.id}" ... />
<p:messages for="#{student.id}" />
```

Comment: @Kaizen I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve with that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: oh shoot,that was to another question wrong place. Back to yours . if i am to go by your second solution, how do i use  the `for` attribute on the `inputText` when `ui:repeat` just renders the same component several times,  but not creating new components in the tree. i read this http://stackoverflow.com/q/19131583/7646476

Comment: @Kaizen you're right, I forgot about that. I updated the answer with more correct information.